# Streaming an XmlDocument for POST

Tags: c#, xml, oauth

Do educate me about XML, I feel like a total dunce.

I'm supposed to send XML in a POST header and there's a library with method that takes a string contentType and a System.IO.Stream body.

How?

I suppose the first parameter is "text/html; charset=utf-8" which limits the type of stream used.

Bonus question: What's the easiest way of creating your XmlDocument? What type of structure do you usually aim to start of with?

Btw the library is the OAuth package from Madgex.

'Preciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [System.Xml.Linq.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).

For example:

```
var document = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", new XAttribute("Attr", "Value")));
var stream = new MemoryStream();
document.Save(stream);
stream.Position = 0;   //Important!

SomeMethod("text/xml", stream);
```

Note that this requires C# 3.0.

Comment: Thank you! It's immediately clear how this will work out beautifully.